# Onefile creation with PyInstaller breaks tkinter window transparency

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, pyinstaller

When I run my project, everything works perfectly. However, when PyInstaller creates the executable file, the window stops being actually click through, it is transparent though.

If you run the following code, everything will work perfectly fine. However, if you run `pyinstaller --onefile examplegui.py` on this file then it will no longer be click through. This bug does not apply for `--onedir` though.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *


def main():

    root = Tk()
    mainframe = Frame(root)
    canv = Canvas(mainframe, height=400, width=400)

    mainframe.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)
    canv.pack()

    canv.create_rectangle(50, 50, 350, 350, fill='red', outline='')

    root.attributes('-transparentcolor', 'red')

    mainloop()


if __name__== '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Nothing in the code you posted is expected to produce a click-through window.  As far as I know, no such effect is even possible in Tkinter alone, you have to use platform-specific code to talk directly to your OS's windowing system.

Comment: @jasonharper The -transparentcolor creates a 300x300 square that is removed from the window, thus making it click through. Once Pyinstaller is used on the script, that square is no longer click through but only see through.

Comment: My test result is that the *transparent region* cannot be clicked through when using 'red' as the transparent color.  However it works when 'white' is used as the transparent color.  So try using another color.

Answer (score 0):

There never seemed to be a solution for this so I might as well answer here since I just remembered this question.
The only solution I found back then to this issue (it seems to be an issue that happens in Windows 7 and sometimes Windows 8) is to drop the onefile and use onedir.

After getting those it is possible to imitate the onefile by using winrar to create SFX archive or something like "Inno Setup".